# Can i use HTML5 with vs2008

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2008-sp1

Please tell me that the vs2008 has support for HTML5 or not?

and also tell me how to use HTML5 with vs2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are a number of locations you can download an extension to enable HTML5 intellisense support in Visual Studio 2008 and 2010.

- [John Dyer's article](http://johndyer.name/post/HTML5-XHTML5-Validation-Schema-for-Visual-Studio-2008.aspx)
- [Mikhail Arkhipov's MSDN extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d)
- [Scott Hanselman's coverage of the Visual Studio 2010 Web Standards Update](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingTheWebStandardsUpdateHTML5SupportForTheVisualStudio2010Editor.aspx)

You use these by selecting the "HTML5" validation support in your IDE's toolbar.  Check the articles for more complete instructions.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 tags works fine with ASP.NET 3.5 (Visual Studio 2008). Just put the HTML5 tag in the ASP.NET control and it should work. Note there will be not intellisense support for it. But once you compile, it wont give you any error.

```
// placeholder is html5 tag but works in .NET 3.5 with no addons
// but not intellisense support
<asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" runat="server" placeholder="YYYY-MM" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Visual Studio is just a tool. Any text editing tool (even Notepad) can be used to write HTML5 webpages. When you type HTML5 tags (e.g.: `<canvas>` tag) in Visual Studio, although it shows validation error with green curvy underline, it will just pass the tags to the HTML output and you can still view it perfectly fine in your browsers.